# Do not stop access to OData while loading new data dumps

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

While new dumps are loaded into OData it seems I am unable to query old info and the counts on the front page are wrong.

Can you change it so OData loads new dumps in the background and only when full loaded switches to them?

[image]

Comment: :) see my edit for an answer

Comment: note all is well in odata land now, latest dump is loaded

Comment: @waffles: thanks! I didn't know what the problem was, so couldn't explain it.

Comment: @waffles: Out of curiosity, how long does an import take?

Answer (score 1):

I'm marking this completed cause now the whole update process is significantly faster from the users perspective, we only see a minute or 2 of downtime when loading new data dumps